# Prepare Não exibe erro

Tags: php, mysql

Alguem sabe o porque não está exibindo erro caso falhe o `execute` do `prepare`?

```
$rs = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO tabela (campo1, campo2, campo3) VALUES (?, ?, ?) ");

$rs->bind_param('sss',
    $_POST['campo1'],
    $_POST['campo2'],
    $_POST['campo3']
    );

$rs->execute();


if ($rs->errno) {
    echo 'Erro: ', $rs->error;
} else {
    echo "<script>window.location='PAGINA.php'</script>";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No seu codigo o if está incorreto

```
if ($rs->errno)
```

está errno e não error.

Caso não de em nada você pode testar o

```
erroInfo()
```

para mais informações segue a documentação com exemplos:

https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/pdo.errorinfo.php

Comment: Tambem existe o termo `errno`, veja https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqli-stmt.errno.php

Comment: ah sim desculpe, foquei apenas no PDO

Comment: Vou marcar como resolvido, o problema era prepare, mudei a o nome do campo  e esqueci de mudar no codigo.